# Features of control and data parallelism in Fortran 90?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, programming-languages, fortran90, language-features

in one of my university papers, I have spotted the question 'Features of control and data parallelism in FORTRAN 90?'

Now according to my understanding, in-built array operations in Fortran 90 is an example of Data Parallelism, as Fortran has the capability to perform operations like addition, multiplication, on array elements with a simple code like : c=a+b ....

But what are control parallelism features in fortran 90 ? And the question was worth 8 marks, so I guess only Array operation for data parallelism won't do, there must be something more....

Help please!!

Comment: Maybe the `WHERE` statement/construct?

Comment: I don't think so... Control parallelism means execution of multiple instructions/tasks concurrently, right ?? in where statement, that doesn't happen.

Comment: I would count the array assignments, `where` and `forall` among data parallelism features. What they mean by "control parallelism" I don't know.

Comment: I guess *control parallelism* might be approximately the same as *MIMD* (it might even cover *MISD*) and *data parallelism* approximately the same as *SIMD*.  If you're not familiar with these acronyms, which derive from *Flynn's taxonomy* for computer architectures, hit your favourite search engine for enlightenment.

Comment: I'd guess, that `elemental` procedures might be an example for MIMD.

Comment: Elemental procedures are a way of telling the Fortran compiler, that the procedure can be applied to an array "element" safely in parallel with other procedures.  It supports, but is not, data parallelism by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Fortran 90 has any control parallelism built into the language.  ("Control parallelism" means two completely different chunks of code can be run in parallel.  It usually goes by the name "task parallelism".)  More modern Fortrans [don't obviously offer this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) as part of the language.

It technically doesn't have data parallelism built-in, either; it "merely" makes it easy for a compiler that wishes to implement data parallelism, to spot it, where the programmer has taken advantage of array and slicing operations.   But that is there for both easier coding, and easier analysis by the compiler.

We clearly don't think of pre F90, e.g, "scalar" Fortran as having data parallelism. 
Scalara Fortran compilers for supercomputers have long had the ability to detect array-level operations by analyzing loops carefully.  Clearly the scalar Fortran languages don't have data parallelism built-in yet the supercomputer compilers find and harness it (not as easily as F90 supercomputer compilers).

So the lesson here is that actualizing data parallelism is a property of the specific compiler, not the language.

But what is there isn't quite enough for good data parallelism.  You also need the ability to talk about the memory layout.  That's not in Fortran 90, either.

There have been a variety of extensions to Fortran that offer both of these, often as pragmas or special comments, so the rest of the program seems like vanilla Fortran, whethere scalar or F90.  Task parallelism is usually available via OpenMP extensions offered by many compilers.

Comment: "More modern Fortrans don't obviously offer this as part of the language"??

Comment: @IanH: Sorry if that's unclear.  I know the F90 standard, and have worked with various supercomputing compilers but its been rather awhile.  I don't know more modern Fortrans (e.g., 2008); looking around on google at an Wikipedia, there's no evidence that I can see that more modern Fortrans offer these additional features.  (If you have such evidence, feel free to comment or add your own answer).

Comment: A parallel execution model was the headline feature of Fortran 2008.

Comment: @IanH: Good.  Can you elaborate on it? What does "parallel execution model" mean?  Why syntax?  What requirements on compilers to implement it?  What compilers actually do?

Comment: See ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1801-N1850/N1824.pdf.  There are a number of implementations.

Comment: OK, so no control parallelism in F90.  F2008 compilers may have control paralellism in the form of co-arrays and the corresponding execution model.  From the little I read in your PDF, it seems the actual data parallelism is still left to the compiler, not the language.